# Switch case over multiple types, how do I set a case to catch all errors from a certain import

Tags: go

This is how the code looks like now:

```
        if err != nil {
            switch v := err.(type) {
            case *net.OpError:
                // do something network related
            case *app.ErrorResponse:
                // do something app related
            default:
                // generic response
```

I want to change the **first** condition to catch all network related errors,
meaning anything under "net"

How do I do that?

Comment: There is no magical way to do that.  You could potentially use reflection, but that also gets complicated, especially for errors which can be wrapped.

Comment: You will have to manually list all types.

Answer (score -2):

So apparently, you can do this with url.Error:

```
    if err != nil {
        switch v := err.(type) {
        case *url.Error:
            // do something network related
        case *app.ErrorResponse:
            // do something app related
        default:
            // generic response
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: It catches all the errors I managed to throw at it, though I admit do not fully understand why

Comment: That's a likely indication that the question is an XY problem.  The question asks about catching all errors in a given package.  This answer does _not_ do that. Although in practice, perhaps all of the errors you care about are instances of `*url.Error`, but that would be coincidence.